# What happened to the VHDX specification from Microsoft?

Tags: hyper-v, vhd

The VHD specification was made public in 2006. The new VHDX spec was made available in 2012. Unfortunately, all the Microsoft links to it are now dead. Did Microsoft change their mind about making this public? Or, is it just an honest mistake?

Comment: Checked much later and it is now available from Microsoft at https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=34750

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that the link was later provided by Microsoft in a different location. 
As of August 2017, it is at https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=34750

Answer (score 1):

It's been hosted on the [Open Specifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/main/ms-openspeclp/3589baea-5b22-48f2-9d43-f5bea4960ddb) site for quite some time. As of March 2019 the [latest version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-vhdx/83e061f8-f6e2-4de1-91bd-5d518a43d477) is 4.0.